# Composing Monadic Functions with `<=<`

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand the `<=<` function:

```
ghci> :t (<=<)
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
```

As I understand it, I give it 2 functions and an `a`, and then I'll get an `m c`.

So, why doesn't this example compile?

```
import Control.Monad

f :: a -> Maybe a
f = \x -> Just x

g :: a -> [a]
g = \x -> [x]

foo :: Monad m => a -> m c
foo x = f <=< g x
```

For `foo 3`, I would expect `Just 3` as a result.

But I get this error:

```
File.hs:10:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Maybe c0'
                with actual type `[a]'
    In the return type of a call of `g'
    Probable cause: `g' is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of `(<=<)', namely `g x'
    In the expression: f <=< g x Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two errors here.

First, `(<=<)` only composes monadic functions if they share the same monad.  In other words, you can use it to compose two `Maybe` functions:

```
(<=<) :: (b -> Maybe c) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe c)
```

... or two list functions:

```
(<=<) :: (b -> [c]) -> (a -> [b]) -> (a -> [c])
```

... but you cannot compose a list function and maybe function this way.  The reason for this is that when you have a type signature like this:

```
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c)
```

... the compiler will ensure that all the `m`s must match.

The second error is that you forgot to parenthesize your composition.  What you probably intended was this:

```
(f <=< g) x
```

... if you omit the parentheses the compiler interprets it like this:

```
f <=< (g x)
```

An easy way to fix your function is just to define a helper function that converts `Maybe`s to lists:

```
maybeToList :: Maybe a -> [a]
maybeToList  Nothing = []
maybeToList (Just a) = [a]
```

This function actually has the following two nice properties:

```
maybeToList . return = return

maybeToList . (f <=< g) = (maybeToList . f) <=< (maybeToList . g)
```

... which are functor laws if you treat `(maybeToList .)` as analogous to `fmap` and treat `(<=<)` as analogous to `(.)` and `return` as analogous to `id`.

Then the solution becomes:

```
(maybeToList . f <=< g) x
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that, in

```
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
```

`m` is static -- You're trying to substitute both `[]` and `Maybe` for `m` in the definition -- that won't type check.

You can use `<=<` to compose functions of the form `a -> m b` where `m` is a *single* monad. Note that you can use *different* type arguments though, you don't need to be constrained to the polymorphic `a`.

Here's an example of using this pattern constrained to the list monad:

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f x = [x, x^2]

g :: Int -> [String]
g 0 = []
g x = [show x]

λ> :t g <=< f
g <=< f :: Int -> [String]
λ> g <=< f $ 10
["10","100"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix monads together.  When you see the signature

```
(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
```

The `Monad m` is only a single Monad, not two different ones.  If it were, the signature would be something like

```
(<=<) :: (Monad m1, Monad m2) => (b -> m2 c) -> (a -> m1 b) -> a -> m2 c
```

But this is not the case, and in fact would not really be possible in general.  You *can* do something like

```
f :: Int -> Maybe Int
f 0 = Just 0
f _ = Nothing

g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g x = if even x then Just x else Nothing

h :: Int -> Maybe Int
h = f <=< g
```