# Picking a random line from a file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to have Haskell pick a random line from a file and print it.  My attempt is below:

```
import Data.Random.Extras (choice)
main :: IO ()
main = do
  filecontents <- readFile "wordlist.txt"
  let words = lines filecontents
  let word = choice $ words
  word >>= putStrLn
```

The last line is where the error occurs.  `>>=` expects an `IO String`, but `word` is a `Data.RVar.RVar String`.  (The variable is called `word' because each line should be one word.)

I have read the docs for RVar but after some hacking, I do not see how to solve my problem.  Any ideas?

I am using ghc 7.6.3 from an installation of the Haskell Platform, OS X 10.9.

The complete error is below:

```
[ 01:46 PM (51) integral:thoth ~/Source/pwgen ] > ghc -o pwgen pwgen.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pwgen.hs, pwgen.o )

pwgen.hs:40:3:
    Couldn't match type `Data.RVar.RVarT
                           Data.Functor.Identity.Identity'
                  with `IO'
    Expected type: IO String
      Actual type: Data.RVar.RVar String
    In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `word'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: word >>= putStrLn
    In the expression:
      do { filecontents <- readFile "wordlist.txt";
           let words = lines filecontents;
           let word = choice $ words;
           word >>= putStrLn }
```

Finally, I am aware that there are more efficient ways to pick a random line from a file.  I'm just going for the bare minimum that works.  I am also very much a Haskell beginner and may have some fundamental misconceptions, especially regarding IO and monads.

Comment: You'll have to run `choice words` using `runRVarT`, which requires a seed parameter.  The error message you see here is saying that it can't match the `RVar String` type with `IO String`, since [`RVar` is not the same monad as `IO`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560448/composing-monadic-functions-with/25560521)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
import Data.Random
```

and then modify main

```
main = do
...
  let word = sample $ choice words
  putStrLn =<< word
```

This works because when you import `Data.Random` it contains an instance of `MonadRandom` for `IO` and gives you `sample` as a convenient wrapper for `runRVar` with a generator obtained from the IO monad.

Comment: `putStrLn =<< (sample . choice . lines) =<< readFile "wordlist.txt"` if you like pointfree golf :)